# How do I use a loop to join strings together and return the result?

Tags: python, string, loops

My code

```
def joinStrings(*stringList):

    for gallery in stringList:
        return gallery

joinStrings('john', 'ate', 'a', 'sandwich')
```

How can I fix this to have the for loop join the strings? I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)?

Comment: Well, where's the bit where you are expecting the joining to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
''.join(['john', 'ate', 'a', 'sandwich'])
```

You can place the desired separator (space, comma, ...) or just no separator between the first `''`

You can do it in a for-loop, but it's going to be inefficient as string "addition"/concatenation doesn't scale well (but of course it's possible):

```
def joinStrings(mylist)
  s = ""
  for item in mylist:
     s += item
     s += "" #Place your seperator here
  return s

johnlist = 'john', 'ate', 'a', 'sandwich'
joinStrings(johnlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def joinStrings(stringList):
    output = ""
    for gallery in stringList:
        output += gallery
        output += " "
    output = output[:-1] #remove last space
    return output

joinStrings('john', 'ate', 'a', 'sandwich')
```